# Simple thing esc_url query

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, html

I have code which produces a message when an item is added to cart. I want the button on the message to link to www.melodylakerart.com/shop but cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to work. Can anyone help? I'm sure this is just a tiny change. And im sure its just the wc_get_checkout_url () bit that needs to change. But i cant get it to accept the pure web address.

Any help appreciated. Tearing hair out!

[image: Screenshot]

```
function ace_add_to_cart_message_html( $message, $products ) {
    $count = 0;
    $titles = array();
    foreach ( $products as $product_id => $qty ) {
        $titles[] = ( $qty > 1 ? absint( $qty ) . ' &times; ' : '' ) . sprintf( _x( '&ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), strip_tags( get_the_title( $product_id ) ) );
        $count += $qty;
    }
    $titles     = array_filter( $titles );


    $added_text = sprintf( _n(
        '%s has been added to your cart - pay below, or keep shopping', // Singular
        '%s has been added to your cart - pay below, or keep shopping', // Plural
        $count, // Number of products added
        'woocommerce' // Textdomain
    ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );
    $message    = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url(wc_get_checkout_url () ), esc_html__( 'Keep shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    return $message;
} 
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'ace_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: If it doesn't do what you expect it to do, what does it actually do instead? Keep in mind 3rd party plugins such as WooCommerce are offtopic here, your question could get closed as offtopic

Comment: Thanks. As it is , clicking the button takes you to the checkout page. I want it to take you to www.melodylakerart.com/shop instead.

Happy to post this elsewhere if you can let me know where's best

Answer (score 0):

Change `wc_get_checkout_url()` to `get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) )`. Please let me know if this works, I am not that familiar with WooCommerce.

Comment: I have edited my suggestion from `woocommerce_get_page_id()` to `wc_get_page_id`, apparently the former function is deprecated.